# Combine multiple objects into new object

Tags: c#, linq

For my issue, I have a list of objects (Producers).

For each producer record, there are some properties (ID, DisplayName, and StateCode).

There can be multiple items in the list that have the same ID & DisplayName, but different StateCodes.

I am having trouble querying this to give me a distinct list of Producers with each of their possible StateCodes in a new object.

I would prefer to have the new objects to have the ID, DisplayName, and a List which contains each StateCode of theirs.

Can someone point out the proper way I could create this new list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for LINQ's `GroupBy`:

```
var groups = producerList.GroupBy(p => new { p.ID, p.DisplayName });
```

group on the 2 properties, then your groups' values will be an IEnumerable of `StateCode`s